# Polynomial Regression nonsense Predictions

Tags: r, regression, prediction

Suppose I want to fit a linear regression model with degree two (orthogonal) polynomial and then predict the response. Here are the codes for the first model (m1)

```
x=1:100
y=-2+3*x-5*x^2+rnorm(100)
m1=lm(y~poly(x,2))
prd.1=predict(m1,newdata=data.frame(x=105:110))
```

Now let's try the same model but instead of using $poly(x,2)$, I will use its columns like:

```
m2=lm(y~poly(x,2)[,1]+poly(x,2)[,2])
prd.2=predict(m2,newdata=data.frame(x=105:110))
```

Let's look at the summaries of m1 and m2.

```
> summary(m1)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2))

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.50347 -0.48752 -0.07085  0.53624  2.96516 

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept) -1.677e+04  9.912e-02 -169168   <2e-16 ***
poly(x, 2)1 -1.449e+05  9.912e-01 -146195   <2e-16 ***
poly(x, 2)2 -3.726e+04  9.912e-01  -37588   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.9912 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:     1,      Adjusted R-squared:     1 
F-statistic: 1.139e+10 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16 

> summary(m2)

Call:
lm(formula = y ~ poly(x, 2)[, 1] + poly(x, 2)[, 2])

Residuals:
     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
-2.50347 -0.48752 -0.07085  0.53624  2.96516 

Coefficients:
                  Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)     -1.677e+04  9.912e-02 -169168   <2e-16 ***
poly(x, 2)[, 1] -1.449e+05  9.912e-01 -146195   <2e-16 ***
poly(x, 2)[, 2] -3.726e+04  9.912e-01  -37588   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1 

Residual standard error: 0.9912 on 97 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:     1,      Adjusted R-squared:     1 
F-statistic: 1.139e+10 on 2 and 97 DF,  p-value: < 2.2e-16
```

So m1 and m2 are basically the same. Now let's look at the predictions prd.1 and prd.2

```
> prd.1
        1         2         3         4         5         6 
-54811.60 -55863.58 -56925.56 -57997.54 -59079.52 -60171.50 

> prd.2
         1          2          3          4          5          6 
  49505.92   39256.72   16812.28  -17827.42  -64662.35 -123692.53
```

Q1: Why prd.2 is significantly different from prd.1?

Q2: How can I obtain prd.1 using the model m2?

Comment: Not an answer, but sufficiently high values of R-squared (0.99 something) always freak me out...

Comment: That's not a problem at all. We can change $y$ with something like $y=-2+3*x-5*x^2+x^5+rnorm(100,15)$ and R-squared reduces to 95%, but the problem remains for the predictions.

Comment: The first model's results look like an ill-conditioned matrix somewhere. The predictions simply follow from the nonsense coefficients estimated by the first model.

Comment: The collinearity is huge, as is common with polynomial terms. This can lead to the ill-conditioning @DeerHunter mentioned. After that, you used results to extrapolate, compounding the danger. The differences in prd could be due to different rounding in the two models.

Comment: @ Peter Flom, poly creates orthogonal polynomials (by default) so it will reduce multicollinearity significantly (Actually that's the whole reason of using poly!) For example in model m2, the variance inflation factor (VIF) is around 1, so the multicollinearity is not a problem. (You can check it with package car and then vif(m2))

Comment: The differences between `m1` and `m2` of any consequence (that is, apart from how the IVs are named) occur only for the `$assign` and `$terms` members. The difference in behavior depends on the internals of the `lm` class and, in particular, on how `predict.lm` behaves.  That makes this question suitable for SO, where a community of `R` experts should be able to handle it well.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`m1` is the right way to do this. `m2` is entering a whole world of pain...

To do predictions from `m2`, the model needs to know it was fitted to an orthogonal set of basis functions, so that it uses the same basis functions for the extrapolated new data values. Compare: `poly(1:10,2)[,2]` with `poly(1:12,2)[,2]` - the first ten values are not the same. If you fit the model explicitly with `poly(x,2)` then `predict` understands all that and does the right thing.

What you have to do is make sure your predicted locations are transformed using the same set of basis functions as used to create the model in the first place. You can use `predict.poly` for this  (note I call my explanatory variables `x1` and `x2` so that its easy to match the names up):

```
px = poly(x,2)
x1 = px[,1]
x2 = px[,2]

m3 = lm(y~x1+x2)

newx = 90:110
pnew = predict(px,newx) # px is the previous poly object, so this calls predict.poly

prd.3 = predict(m3, newdata=data.frame(x1=pnew[,1],x2=pnew[,2]))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. That answers my questions completely. The reason I asked my 2nd question is this: Suppose we fit a polynomial of degree 5 like m4=lm(y~poly(x,5)). Then after fitting we want to fit a new model (m5) by dropping two terms: i.e. the polynomials of degree 2 and 4. And finally do some prediction with this final model (m5). I couldn't do this by using just m4. However, this can be done by using your argument and model m3 as you mentioned.